# How to disable recent files when Taskbar and starmenu properties doesnt display start menu tab to disable it

Tags: windows-10

I want to disable recent files in my Windows 10. I'm following this video [How to disable recent files on Windows® 10 Technical Preview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afSITxyJkVg) but I dont get the "Start Menu" tab in my Windows 10. The other tab menu options are the same (though they are in spanish). How do I disable recent files when Taskbar and starmenu properties doesnt display start menu tab to disable it?

Video:

[image]

Mine:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the following registry setting.

1. run the **regedit** as administrator
2. find the path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
3. right-click the blank place on the right hand and click new **DWord**
4. Then name it as **Start_TrackDocs** , and modified its value to **0** to turn off recent files.